# select data by passing a value in where clause if the value match then return that data otherwise return all data

Tags: sql, oracle

select data by passing a value in where clause  if the value match then return matches data otherwise return all data.
Consider following example

```
ID  Name
1   ABC
2   DEF
3   GHI
4   JKL
```

When pass id = 1 the return row 1 when pass null value or 0 then return all data.

Comment: `where id = &value or &value = 0 or &value is null`

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
   SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT T.*,
          SUM(CASE WHEN T.ID = <YOUR_VALUE(0,1,NULL, or any)> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER () AS SM 
     FROM YOUR_TABLE T)
    WHERE SM = 0 OR ID = <YOUR_VALUE(0,1,NULL, or any)>
```

You need to replace `<YOUR_VALUE(0,1,NULL)>` with a value that you want to pass.

For values 0 and 1, results are as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM
  2    (SELECT T.*,
  3    SUM(CASE WHEN T.ID = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER () AS SM
  4   FROM YOUR_TABLE T)
  5      WHERE SM = 0 OR ID = 0 ;

        ID NAM         SM
---------- --- ----------
         1 ABC          0
         2 DEF          0
         3 GHI          0
         4 JKL          0

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM
  2    (SELECT T.*,
  3    SUM(CASE WHEN T.ID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER () AS SM
  4   FROM YOUR_TABLE T)
  5      WHERE SM = 0 OR ID = 1;

        ID NAM         SM
---------- --- ----------
         1 ABC          1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where id = 1 or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = 1);
```

Or as a passed-in value:

```
select t.*
from t
where id = :input or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = :input);
```

Note that this works for `NULL` values as well, because the `where` in the subquery would evaluate to `NULL` if `:input` is `NULL`.